# Need to know the Xpath expression for finding values of label tags in DOM

Tags: java, webdriver

```
<div id="content1customId" class="tabcontent" style="display: block;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="text-align: right; width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td height="25px">
<label style="color: red;"> * </label>
<label title="INGRESE TIPO DE DOCUMENTO">Tipo De Documento   </label>
</td>
<td align="left">
<td align="left">
<td>
<td align="left">
<td align="left">
```

This is the DOM structure present above in which I need to find ALL the "label" tags having attribute "title" so that I can further extract the attribute's value. For example:

```
<label title="INGRESE TIPO DE DOCUMENTO">Tipo De Documento   </label>
```

I want to extract "Tipo De Documento" text from the above for which I am writing a xpath i.e. `//label[@title]`.

and then using in my code like this:

```
List<WebElement> dvLable = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[title]"));

for (WebElement dvl : dvLable) {
        String tdLabName = dvl.getText();
        System.out.println("This is label: " + tdLabName);
    }
```

Similarly, I want to find such 'text' value for all the labels presented across the page DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you put "@title" it should work:

```
List<WebElement> dvLable = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[@title]"));
```

Comment: Hi Surya, I did try and got the results like this:

This is label: Consecuencia-1   
This is label: Consecuencia-2   
This is label: Consecuencia-3   
This is label: Consecuencia-4   
This is label: 
This is label: 
This is label:

I am not empty lables for remaining label which are not empty in DOM.

Comment: Hi, you need all the "label" irrespective of "title" attribute? then try below code:                                         List<WebElement> dvLable = driver.findElements(By.tagName("label"));
for (WebElement dvl : dvLable) {
 if(dvl.isDisplayed()){
        String tdLabName = dvl.getText();
        System.out.println("This is label: " + tdLabName);
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
List<WebElement> dvLable = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[@title and @title!='']"));
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, however, it skips the labels if 'title' attribute is missing.

Comment: @user1551908 according to you question that's what you wanted: "find ALL 'label' tags having attribute 'title'" meaning not to collect labels without titles.